# How to add all elements in list to Abstract Syntax Tree without knowing how many elements?

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree

So I have an AbstractSyntaxTreeNode.java class (here is part of it)

```
public abstract class ASTreeNode implements Iterable<ASTreeNode>{

protected List<ASTreeNode> children;

protected ASTreeNode(){
  children = new LinkedList<ASTreeNode>();
}

protected ASTreeNode(ASTreeNode... children){
  this();
  for(ASTreeNode c: children)
{
  this.addChild(c);
}
```

And then I have another class Operation that extends ASTreeNode

```
public class Operation extends ASTreeNode
{
  char s;

  private Operation(Term t)
  {
  //QUESTION REGARDING THIS PART
    super(t, t.getChild(0), t.getChild(1));
  }
}
```

How do I throw in all of object t's (which also extends ASTreeNode) children into the super ctor arguments? Without hardcoding it like that? I tried super(t, t.children) but the constructor does not take a List in the argument, only ASTreeNodes 
are taken.

Oh and this is class term

```
public class Term extends ASTreeNode
{
  char symbol;

private Term(Factor f)
{
  super(f, f.getChild(0));
}
}
```

And theres a bunch more classes that send up their children into another node

Answer (score 1):

Add a constructor in ASTreeNode that accept's a List as it's argument.

```
public abstract class ASTreeNode ... {

    public ASTreeNode(List<? extends ASTreeNode> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
}

public class Operation extends ASTreeNode {
    char s;

    private Operation(Term t) {
        super(t.getChildren());
        this.addChild(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to do it without editing class ASTreeNode? We're not supposed to change that file (it was given to us to help us with our homework)

I will double check to see if I can change it, thank you for the help!

Comment: Do you have a method that will get let you get all the children fo a `ASTreeNode`?

Comment: Ooops I figured out that I don't actually need to do this. I think. Because the tree is already constructed, I just need to go through the tree by doing something like root = root.getChild(0) or root.getChild(1) and put that in some kind of recursion or loop. Sorry for the late response and thanks for helping